# number of requests in apache access_log

Tags: apache, unix, access-log

I am trying to find the number of requests in the apache access_log. That is, some unix command that will return the number of requests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | wc -l
```